# List top 10 Results between Two Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am currently having an issue with trying to list the top 10 rows between two tables. Table one has columns (name, gold, id), and table two has columns (name, gold, id).

How would I list the top 10 gold between the two tables and prevent a duplicate row from being listed?

Both tables have nearly identical data. After a period of time, one table updates the other table, kinda like a backup table. But sometimes table2's data can be different than table1's data until the update takes place.

Say table1 has rows like...

```
 (Josh, 500, 1),
 (Bob, 600, 2),
 (Jim, 687, 3),
 (John, 777, 4),
 (Jack, 888, 5)
```

and table2 has rows like...

```
 (Josh, 488, 1),
 (sue, 1000, 6),
 (Joe, 6882, 7),
 (John2, 77, 8),
 (Jay, 874, 9)
```

How would I list the top 10 gold between the two tables without showing duplicate rows? I want table2's data to take priority over table1. I am currently using this method...

```
SELECT table1.gold AS mysum, table2.gold AS mysum2 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id 
ORDER BY mysum DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

then I am just checking the results of of this query and using either mysum or mysum2 depending on if mysum2 is set.

This doesn't exactly work the way I want though because if mysum2 is set, it will still be listed as a top 10 result of table1 and be in an incorrect position on the list.

Comment: If `table1` and `table2` have a row with the same ID should they both show or does one table's row take precedence? Like `Josh` is in both tables, would they both show or just one?

Comment: This is what `union` is for. There's an example on the [docs page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) which is pretty much exactly what you want ("To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result...").

Comment: Yes, if the answer to my above question is that both Josh's should be shown then `union` would do the trick.

Comment: Table2 would take precedence. Table2 can be thought of as online users. And table1 can be thought of as offlineusers. I do not want duplicate rows between the two tables to be displayed. Table2 data should be displayed in the event of a duplicate row. I am checking out union now, but I am confused how I would limit the rows to 10 between two tables and show only the top results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```
SELECT t.g FROM
(
  SELECT IFNULL(table2.gold, table1.gold) AS g
  FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id 
) t
ORDER BY t.g DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I don't want the SUM of gold between both tables. I only want one value or the other value, depending on if the other value exists in table2. Your help is much appreciated though.

Comment: @shader2199 I updated my answer based on your feedback, please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be what I was looking for actually :). Removed the SUM functions, gave the combined tables an alias, and made sure that table2 was selected before table1 to give it priority, and now things seem to work fine for me. Very much appreciated. Lol. Was searching for a few hours for the answer. I was looking at table joins though and not UNION. (Never really had to use Union)